# mvc3 razor conditional wrapper div

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor

What's the best way to handle something like this:

**Razor Code:**

```
@if(!disableRowDiv)
{
    <div class="row">
}

<div>some content here</div>

@if(!disableRowDiv)
{
    </div>
}
```

So that the Razor engine doesn't produce this error :

**Parser Error Message:**

> The if block is missing a closing "}" character.  Make sure you have a matching "}" character for all the "{" characters within this block, and that none of the "}" characters are being interpreted as markup.

Answer (score 75, accepted):

This should work

```
@if(!disableRowDiv)
{
    @:<div class="row">
}
<div>some content here</div>
@if(!disableRowDiv)
{
    @:</div>
}
```

Comment: +1 super useful and so hard to find. If you find MS documentation for it please provide the link here.