# Razor syntax - how to conditionally wrap some inner HTML

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, razor

In Razor, there's a curious rule about only allowing **closed** HTML within an `if` block.

See:

[Razor doesn't understand unclosed html tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4809694/razor-doesnt-understand-unclosed-html-tags)

But I have a situation where I want to exclude some outer, wrapping elements under certain conditions. I don't want to repeat all the inner HTML, which is a fair amount of HTML and logic.

*Is the only way around the problem to make yet another partial view for the inner stuff to keep it DRY?*

Without any other re-use for this new partial, it feels really awkward, bloaty. I wonder if the rule is a limitation of Razor or simply a nannying (annoying) feature.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

You can use `Html.Raw(mystring)`. In `myString` you can write whatever you want, for example a tag opening or closing, without getting any errors at all. I.e.

```
if (condition) {
  @Html.Raw("<div>")
}

if (condition) {
  @Html.Raw("</div>")
}
```

NOTE: the `@Html.Raw("<div>")` can be written in a shorter, alternative form, like this: `@:<div>`

You can also [create your own html helpers](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/older-versions/views/creating-custom-html-helpers-cs) for simplifying the razor syntax. These helpers could receive the condition parameter, so that you can do something like this:

```
@Html.DivOpen(condition)

@Html.DivClose(condition)
```

or more complicated helpers that allow to specify attributes, tag name, and so on.

Nor the `Raw`, neither the html helpers will be detected as "tags" so you can use them freely.

**The Best Way to do it**

It would be much safer to implement something like the `BeginForm` html helper. You can look at the source code. It's easy to implement: you simply have to write the opening tag in the constructor, and the closing tag in the `Dispose` method. The adavantage of this technique is that you will not forget to close a conditionally opened tag.

You need to implement this html helper (an extension method declared in a static class):

```
  public static ConditionalDiv BeginConditionalDiv(this HtmlHelper html, 
    bool condition)
  {
      ConditionalDiv cd = new ConditionalDiv(html, condition);
      if (condition) { cd.WriteStart(); }
      return cd; // The disposing will conditionally call the WriteEnd()
  }
```

Which uses a class like this:

```
  public class ConditionalDiv : IDisposable
  {
      private HtmlHelper Html;
      private bool _disposed;
      private TagBuilder Div;
      private bool Condition;

      public ConditionalDiv(HtmlHelper html, bool condition)
      {
          Html = html;
          Condition = condition;
          Div = new TagBuilder("div");
      }

      public void Dispose()
      {
          Dispose(true /* disposing */);
          GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
      }

      protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
      {
        if (!_disposed)
        {
            _disposed = true;
            if (Condition) { WriteEnd(); }
        }
      }

       public void WriteStart()
       {
           Html.ViewContext.Writer.Write(Div.ToString(TagRenderMode.StartTag));
       }

       private void WriteEnd()
       {
           Html.ViewContext.Writer.Write(Div.ToString(TagRenderMode.EndTag));
       }
  }
```

You can use this with the same pattern as `BeginForm`. (Disclaimer: this code is not fully tested, but gives an idea of how it works. You can accept extra parameters for attributes, tag names and so on).

Comment: Thanks - the question is really to see what strategies for this people are using out in the wild.

Comment: Woah. That's a pretty admirable answer.

Comment: Thanks. Helped me and I think @:<div> is better because it don't need to change " to ' or somethings other if HTML was complex. see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11969070/mvc3-razor-conditional-wrapper-div

Comment: The `BeginConditionalDiv` extension method can also return `null` (or a no-op `IDisposable` class) instead, so you don't need to pass the condition into the `ConditionalDiv` class and have additional code to write the conditional start/end tag.

Comment: @Ronald I don't understand what you mean. Can you explain it?

Comment: The helper method can be simplified to `return condition ? new ConditionalDiv(html, condition) : null;` if the `ConditionalDiv` writes the start tag in the constructor and end tag in the dispose method.

Comment: My sample follows the same pattern of `BeginForm`. It doesn't make any difference in the Razor usage. Apart from this, for me it's a smell to do actions in constructors: they should only be used to initialize objects.

Answer (score 7):

Declare razor helper using `@helper HeplerName()`, call by `@HeplerName()` anywhere. And you can add params if you want.

```
@if (condition)
{
  <div class="wrapper">
    @MyContent()
  </div>
}
else
{
  @MyContent()
}

@helper MyContent()
{
  <img src="/img1.jpg" />
}
```

Edit (thanks to @Kolazomai for bringing up the point in comments):

ASP.NET Core 3.0 no longer supports `@helper` but supports HTML markup in method body. New case will look like this:

```
@if (condition)
{
  <div class="wrapper">
    @{ MyContent(); }
  </div>
}
else
{
  @{ MyContent(); }
}

@{
  void MyContent()
  {
    <img src="/img1.jpg" />
  }
}
```

Comment: ASP.NET Core no longer supports ```@helper```.
Use ```@{ void MyContent() { <img src="/img1.jpg" /> } }``` instead and call via ```@{ MyContent(); }```.

Comment: @Kolazomai thanks for your input, added this to my post.

Answer (score 1):

The following code is based on the answer of @JotaBe, but simplified and extendable:

```
public static class HtmlHelperExtensions
{
    public static IDisposable BeginTag(this HtmlHelper htmlHelper, string tagName, bool condition = true, object htmlAttributes = null)
    {
        return condition ? new DisposableTagBuilder(tagName, htmlHelper.ViewContext, htmlAttributes) : null;
    }
}

public class DisposableTagBuilder : TagBuilder, IDisposable
{
    protected readonly ViewContext viewContext;
    private bool disposed;

    public DisposableTagBuilder(string tagName, ViewContext viewContext, object htmlAttributes = null) : base(tagName)
    {
        this.viewContext = viewContext;

        if (htmlAttributes != null)
        {
            this.MergeAttributes(HtmlHelper.AnonymousObjectToHtmlAttributes(htmlAttributes));
        }

        this.Begin();
    }

    protected virtual void Begin()
    {
        this.viewContext.Writer.Write(this.ToString(TagRenderMode.StartTag));
    }

    protected virtual void End()
    {
        this.viewContext.Writer.Write(this.ToString(TagRenderMode.EndTag));
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        this.Dispose(true);
        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }

    protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (!this.disposed)
        {
            this.disposed = true;

            this.End();
        }
    }
}
```

This can be used the following way within Razor views:

```
@using (Html.BeginTag("div"))
{
    <p>This paragraph is rendered within a div</p>
}

@using (Html.BeginTag("div", false))
{
    <p>This paragraph is rendered without the div</p>
}

@using (Html.BeginTag("a", htmlAttributes: new { href = "#", @class = "button" }))
{
    <span>And a lot more is possible!</span>
}
```

Comment: This worked very good. Thank you. I tried to convert it to ASP.NET Core MVC without luck. It appears the this.ToString(TagRenderMode) overload is missing on .NET Core.

Answer (score 0):

This is IMO the most convenient way to achieve this:

```
[HtmlTargetElement(Attributes = RenderAttributeName)]
public class RenderTagHelper : TagHelper
{
    private const string RenderAttributeName = "render";
    private const string IncludeContentAttributeName = "include-content";

    [HtmlAttributeName(RenderAttributeName)]
    public bool Render { get; set; }

    [HtmlAttributeName(IncludeContentAttributeName)]
    public bool IncludeContent { get; set; }

    public override void Process(TagHelperContext context, TagHelperOutput output)
    {
        if (!Render)
        {
            if (IncludeContent)
                output.SuppressOutput();
            else
                output.TagName = null;
        }

        output.Attributes.RemoveAll(RenderAttributeName);
        output.Attributes.RemoveAll(IncludeContentAttributeName);
    }
}
```

Then, you just use it like this:

```
<div render="[bool-value]" include-content="[bool-value]">
    ...
</div>
```